# NextJs - Link to scroll to a section in same page with offset

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJs. I already have a link on my header section that scrolls to another section. Due to my navigation bar being fixed on top and having 90px i need the scroll to offset that amount.

```
        <Link href='/#testimonials'>
          Testimonials
        </Link>
```

I did try to use offset={} but it does not work as it does with react-scroll.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I normally create an invisible empty element above with the id I would like it to link to. There could be a more professional solution but it's simple, straight forward, and it's never given me a problem.

HTML:

```html
<div id="testimonialsWrapper">
  ...

  {/* you could also use a span/other tag here */}
  <div id="testimonials"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#testimonialsWrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#testimonials {
  position: absolute;
  top: -90px;
  left: 0;
}
```